# how to constraint the Type parameter to a certain interface only

Tags: c#

Would it be possible to constraint a Type parameter to only allow caller to pass in class type that implements a certain interface?  Take below as example:

```
public void RegisterProcessors(params Type[] types)
```

As it is now, caller can pass in any class type to this method.  For example:

```
RegisterProcessors(typeof(string));
```

But what I really want is to only allow caller to pass in type that implements the IProcessor interface.  Is that possible?  Something like below, of course, below is syntactically wrong

```
public void RegisterProcessors(params Type<IProcessor>[] types)
```

Comment: Why don't use a generic method or directly pass `IProcessor` collection?

Comment: Do you want to constraint at compile time? Could you not do it at runtime?

Comment: My process will be a multi threaded process.  It will instantiate as many processor as required.  Caller simply need to pass in the class type.  Of course, I can have the caller pass in the IProcessor object and use it to get the class type.  But class type would be preferred.

Comment: @Camilo, yes, that is how I'm coding it now.  If caller passed in a class type that does not implement IProceesor, it throws exception.  But it would be nice if there is a way to do restrict it at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

No, basically. If you were using generics, you could use

```cs
public void RegisterProcessor<T>() where T : IProcessor
```

But you can't combine that with `params`, so the caller would need to invoke it once per type. Which might be fine.

Comment: And to make it simpler for the caller, `RegisterProcessor` could return `this` for easy chaining